# Itext7 Canvas set text to right border

Tags: canvas, itext

I am using Itext7 in my java project to fill the pdf form. Is there any way to set text extension in canvas to the left from absolute position? For example, i set text to right top corner, and it extends to the left top corner as longer i increase its length. As i mentioned before, i use canvas.

Example of adding text

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(dest));


    PdfCanvas canvas1 = new PdfCanvas(document.getPage(1));
    canvas1.beginText().setFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA), 7)
            .moveText(500, 592.5)
            .showText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY").format(invoice.getDate()))
            .endText();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `PdfCanvas`, you are writing PDF operators straight to the content stream. For instance: `beginText()` writes **`BT`** and `endText()` writes **`ET`**. There is no PDF operator to show text aligned to one side or another. With `moveText()`, you move to a coordinate, and `showText()` begins writing the text from that coordinate on from left to right.

If you insist on using `PdfCanvas` (and nothing but `PdfCanvas`), you need to calculate the length of the text when using 7pt Helvetica. And you have to do the Math to calculate where that text should start.

If it's OK for you to let iText do the Math, you should create a `Canvas` object from the `PdfCanvas` and the `PdfDocument` you already have.

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rectangle);
```

Now you can create a `Paragraph` with the text you want to add, and you can define the alignment for the document:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph()
    .add("text").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);
canvas.add(p);
canvas.close();
```

In this case, iText will do all the calculations to compensate for the limited set of PDF operators.